# Bootstrap - Two column layout with text between the columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to create a layout that has two columns, and text between those columns

Something like this:
[image]

But I am running into spacing issues with **twitter bootstrap** to make it actually work. On top of making these items the same width with the text between, they should all be vertically aligned.

Comment: To me, this looks like a 3 column row.

Comment: use jsFiddle or something and show us what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bootstrap answer just a plain simple CSS one. Although you can adapt it to bootstrap easily because the basic underlying principle is the same. Instead of using width percentages that I have used in my example, bootstrap grid system columns can be used instead. Saying all that, you can achieve your desired effect by dividing the wrapper div into 3 columns and then using the display table for parent and table-cell and vertical align middle for the child to place the respective input elements and button elements in its place as needed.

The fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g86p6jqv/1/)

The code snippet follows...

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
}
.leftSide,
.rightSide,
.midPart {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.leftSide {
  width: 45%;
  background: lightgray;
  float: left;
}
.midPart {
  width: 10%;
  background: aqua;
}
.midPart p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.leftSide div,
.rightSide div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.rightSide {
  width: 45%;
  background: lightcyan;
  float: right;
}
button {
  height: 3em;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="leftSide">
    <div>
      <input placeholder="Enter Username" />
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <input placeholder="Enter password" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightSide">
    <div>
      <button>Hello</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="midPart">
    <p>-or-</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps. **Happy coding :)**

**Update::**
***[**Another updated Fiddle without colors](http://jsfiddle.net/g86p6jqv/2/)*****

Answer (score 0):

**You can do that using 3 columns**

## Live Demo jsfiddle

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">.col-sm-6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">.col-sm-6</div>
</div>
    <br/>
  <p>Create an account...............................</p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 test" >

     <form class="form-horizontal vmid" role="form">      
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password"/>
      </div>
    </div></form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-1 test" >
        <p class="asd"> ~OR~</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-5 test" >
    <button type="submit" class="asd btn-primary btn-lg">Facebook</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Style**

```
.vmid{
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
}
.asd{
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-35%);
}
```